# Unhandled handle exception?

Tags: .net, winforms, exception, c++-cli, unhandled

I have a quandary regarding C++ and .Net/WinForms. I have code written to launch a background worker to check user input against a web server. The code is as follows:

```
    try {
        loginworker->RunWorkerAsync();                       
    }
    catch(System::InvalidOperationException^) {}
```

Now, when I run the program and click the login button several times (thus triggering the 'Background worker is already running a task' error), I get an unhandled System::InvalidOperationException at that line of code. Is there something I'm missing here?

I've already written the code in a way that hides the login button until code execution completes on the background worker, but should it not catch the exception?

Collin

Comment: what happens if you do `catch(System::InvalidOperationException& e) { ...something... }`?

Comment: The real bug is trying to swallow exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have you debugger set to break on all exceptions? What happens if you replace the RunWorkerAsync line with `throw gcnew InvalidOperationException();`, and click the button once?

Comment: I believe I do, which would explain it. I've tried using throw on other functions and it does not detect that an exception was thrown.